# Neovim goto definition

Tags: neovim

If I use **gd** or **gD** commands on my functions in neovim, it only jumps to my imports, not to my actual function definitions. I am using **tsserver** LSP for javascript. Also **Treesitter** for javascript has been installed.

```
import { mainObject, analyzeButton, saveButton, generateScriptButton } from './js_modules/utils.js'
import { renderSvgFile } from './js_modules/fileRenderer.js'
import { collectSvgElements, collectDiagramElements } from './js_modules/collectERElements.js'
import { createGraph } from './js_modules/createGraph.js'
import { generateScript } from './js_modules/generateScript.js'

renderSvgFile()

analyzeButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
    mainObject.object = document.getElementById('object').contentDocument
    mainObject.svg = mainObject.object.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0]
    mainObject.nodesArray = mainObject.svg.childNodes
    collectSvgElements(mainObject.nodesArray)
    collectDiagramElements()
    createGraph()
})

generateScriptButton.addEventListener('click', generateScript)
```

Answer (score 14):

Did you configured `gd` to use lsp functions?

Quick and dirty way to do it - is like this:

```lua
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap("n", "gD", "<cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.declaration()<CR>", { noremap = true, silent = true })
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap("n", "gd", "<cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.definition()<CR>", { noremap = true, silent = true })
```

Although i'd recommend doing it during your language-server setup, so that buffers that don't have it, would not try to use this mapping and use the default one. Here's my part of config that does it - [link](https://github.com/BrotifyPacha/nvim/blob/b12fe7e5b52dcee3b3d3e78d031cb01d862a3785/lua/lsp/init.lua#L28-L29)